# How do I install the Moksha window manager on 15.04?

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, moksha

I have Xubuntu 15.04 running through VirtualBox and in an effort to minimize the resources it uses further I was considering switching to Bodhi Linux's Moksha window manager. I have tried adding the Bodhi repo (`deb http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi trusty main`) to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file but as Bodhi is based on LTS releases of Ubuntu I encountered some issues with attempting to install Moksha this way. So instead I cloned the [Moksha GitHub repository](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/moksha) and checked-out the latest release (0.1.0) with:

```
git clone https://github.com/JeffHoogland/moksha
git fetch -p
git checkout 0.1.0
git remote add upstream https://github.com/JeffHoogland/moksha
```

With the last line really just serving to make it easier for me to update this repo when newer releases become available. I then ran `sudo apt-get build-dep e17` as I know that Moksha is forked from Enlightenment 17 and hence its dependencies are similar. After this I proceeded to compile and install Moksha from this source code by following the instructions in the [INSTALL](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/moksha/blob/master/INSTALL) file, namely:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I received no error messages from this at all and everything, from my point of view, ran smoothly. Then I rebooted with `sudo reboot`, so I could try out Moksha but at the lightdm login screen no Moksha option appeared in the list of available session types.

In attempting to follow Muru's suggestions in the comments I copy-pasted `$MOKSHA_BUILD_PATH/data/xsession/enlightenment.desktop` to `/usr/share/xsessions/moksha.desktop` (with `sudo mv`) and I then rebooted and logged in using the Moksha session option that appeared but I was left with a black screen. I then switched to tty1 using `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and logged in and ran `/usr/local/bin/enlightenment_start` (which should have started Mokshra) and I received an error message (which I can't copy here as tty1 doesn't allow me to use clipboard in it). Is there a way I could get this error message while running a Xfce session (as then I could copy-paste it here)? I have tried running `/usr/local/bin/enlightenment_start` while in Xfce but the error it gave was complaining that another window manager was active and because of this it could not launch.

Comment: You might have to manually create a `.desktop` file for Moksha in `/usr/share/xsessions`. Chances are, the necessary files are installed, but an xsession entry wasn't made.

Comment: Thanks, I'm willing it give it a try. So I opened up `xfce.desktop` in Atom, so I could get the gist of how I should format it, but I don't know what's the moksha equivalent to the Exec command, `startxfce4`. Do you know per chance?

Comment: Since Bodhi Linux provides a package, you can manually download their package and loot at its `.desktop` file. The command is `/usr/bin/enlightenment_start` .. which is not surprising, I suppose.

Comment: `/usr/bin/enlightenment_start` doesn't exist on my system it's at `/usr/local/bin/enlightenment_start`. I found a .desktop file in my build directory and I copy-pasted that to `/usr/share/xsessions`. Unfortunately, I then rebooted my Xubuntu machine and selected to log into Moksha and now I'm left with just a black screen.

Answer (score -1):

**Installation of Bodhi Moksha Desktop Environment for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)**

**Step 1:** Add the Bodhi Repo to apt sources

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this below line, at the bottom of the opened file

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/ trusty main
```

**Step 2:** Sync package lists

```
sudo apt update
```

**Step 3:** Install the Bodhi Moksha Desktop

```
sudo apt install moksha
```

---

**To start xsession (rdp) with Bodhi Moksha DE, follow these steps**

**Step 1:** Create/edit .xsession file at the root directory of the user

```
cd ~
sudo nano .xsession
```

**Step 2:** Add this command at the end of the file

```
enlightenment_start
```

That's it, enjoy MOKSHA!

[image]