# How to install Moksha Desktop?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, gui, desktop-environments

I like the [moksha](https://www.bodhilinux.com/moksha-desktop/) destop which Bodhi Linux uses.  Is there not a repo or snap to install moksha on Ubuntu?

The Debian [instructions](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/jeffhoogland/installing-moksha-desktop-on-debian-jessie-110415) seem a bit much for what I would naively expect to be a [package](https://askubuntu.com/q/662479/45156), or even available as a PPA.

Comment: Example, from search ´´moksha ubuntu´´ : https://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/13566-installing-moksha-with-ubuntu-1604/ → add in sources.list : `deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi xenial b4main` → `sudo apt-get install moksha packagekit bodhi-desktop`

Comment: @Thufir - I'd like to know if you tried this? I'm considering banging into onto my Xubuntu machine instead of / alongside XFCE.

Comment: @FiddyBux You'll have to be the guinea pig on this one...but it looks interesting.  Let me know as you go along; I'm interested.  (I think you can just add the packages and then configure startx.)

Comment: @Thufir - I tried the live USB on my system. Doesn't even detect my WiFi card. Not impressed. Also, the Moksha desktop seems a lot slower than openbox I'm using in Bunsenlabs, so I'm going to give this a miss. Hope you have more joy with it.

Comment: @FiddyBux you persuaded me to try openbox?  bunsenlabs?  not familiar, but I'll take a look.

Comment: Bunsenlabs is basically a lightweight Debian Stretch using openbox window manager. I haven't seen anything lighter, other than using no window manager at all and running headless.

Answer (score 2):

**Installation of Bodhi Moksha Desktop Environment for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)**

**Step 1:** Add the Bodhi Repo to apt sources

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this below line, at the bottom of the opened file

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/ jammy b7main
```

**Step 2:** Sync package lists

```
sudo apt update
```

**Step 3:** Install the Bodhi Moksha Desktop

```
sudo apt install moksha
```

---

**To start xsession (rdp) with Bodhi Moksha DE, follow these steps**

**Step 1:** Create/edit .xsession file at the root directory of the user

```
cd ~
sudo nano .xsession
```

**Step 2:** Add this command, at the end of the file

```
enlightenment_start
```

That's it, enjoy MOKSHA!

[image: Bodhi Moksha DE for Ubuntu 22.04]

---

**For other versions of Ubuntu, just replace the line at Step 1**

- Bodhi Moksha for **Ubuntu 20.04** LTS (Focal Fossa)

`deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/ focal b6main`

- Bodhi Moksha for **Ubuntu 18.04** LTS (Bionic Beaver)

`deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/ bionic b5main`

- Bodhi Moksha for **Ubuntu 16.04** LTS (Xenial Xerus)

`deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/ xenial b4main`

- Bodhi Moksha for **Ubuntu 14.04** LTS (Trusty Tahr)

`deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi/ trusty main`

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME YOU ARE A STAR