# Python-related errors when running apt update after adding and removing Bodhi repository

Tags: apt, package-management, python, ppa, system

Error when running update:

```
thufir@bot:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]        
Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease 
Fetched 166 kB in 1s (138 kB/s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN13debListParser12ParseDependsEPKcS1_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_RjRKbSB_SB_RKS7_ version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
Reading package lists... Done
W: Problem unlinking the file auxfiles - Clean (21: Is a directory)
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
thufir@bot:~$
```

There's a possibility this error was introduced by attempting to [add](https://askubuntu.com/q/1041063/45156) repos for bodhi.  The `sources.list` file:

```
thufir@bot:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

#deb [trusted=yes] http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi xenial b4main
thufir@bot:~$
```

*Note that `bodhi`, the last line, is commented out.*  The OS:

```
thufir@bot:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

The apt version:

```
thufir@bot:~$ apt-cache policy apt
apt:
  Installed: 2.2.12~bodhi2
  Candidate: 2.2.12~bodhi2
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.12~bodhi2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Perhaps the problem is a failed update?

Comment: A commented out line in source.list file is for sure not the reason this happens. Can you please check the version of `apt` you have installed with `apt-cache policy apt`.

Comment: The problem is you bhodi  tries have replaced the systems apt package which seems not compatible. Actual version of apt is from bionic-main with version number 1.6.1.

Comment: @Videonauth added to end of question.  thanks.  I did try to update, after the update failed, then I commented out the last line for the `sources` file.  can I just remove bodhi references somehow?  The put back?

Comment: I would try to download the package manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt and then using dpkg to install it, if needed with force. You need to get this back working before attempting a fix on the rest. You might want to check if the aptitude package got overwritten/replaced too.

Comment: As well you should report this erroneous behavior to the bodhi team. You might not be the only one got hit by this, if you can hit me up in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you like.

Comment: You can as well check `/var/log/apt/history.log` which other packages got replaced by your attempt, but for fixing those a working apt package would be good to have.

Comment: Another option to find the packages which have changed is if the bodhi team sticks to the naming using `dpkg -l | grep bodhi`

Comment: @Videonauth and others, thanks for all the help.  It wasn't my laptop, limited time, I just installed bodhi for now so they have something working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you installed some third-party version of the `apt` package but kept the accompanying and apparently incompatible `libapt-pkg5.0` package as it was from Canonical's repositories.

*Normally* you can force packages to their most recent version available for the current Ubuntu release with:

```sh
sudo apt install {PACKAGE_NAME,...}/$(lsb_release -sc)
```

*However in this case* Apt itself is affected and broken so you need to:

1. Download the packages manually from the package repository ([`apt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt), [`libapt-pkg5.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libapt-pkg5.0)).

   1. Make sure that the package's page is for your Ubuntu release (look near the top),
   2. Scroll to the download section at the bottom of each package's page,
   3. click the link for your architecture,
   4. select a suitable download mirror and
   5. store the package files in a location that you can remember for the next step, e. g. `/tmp`.
2. Install the downloaded Deb packages with `dpkg`:

   ```sh
   cd /tmp
   sudo dpkg -i {apt,libapt-pkg5.0}_*.deb
   ```
3. Update your packages to verify that Apt works and make sure that you have the most recent version:

   ```sh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

Comment: how or why did apt itself break?